# ResourceBundle fully qualified name with extensions

Tags: java, resourcebundle, ocpjp

From this book "Oracle Certified Professional Java SE 7 Programmer Exams 1Z0-804 and 1Z0-805: A Comprehensive OCPJP 7"

> A fully qualified resource bundle has the following form:
>   packagequalifier.bundlename + "*" + language + "*" + country + "*" +
>   (variant + "*#" | "#") + script
>   + "-" + extensions

However I cannot put the hyphen in a class name... maybe it's an error and they wanted to put another underscore? Or is there something I am missing about the extensions?
As far as I know for the extension the hyphen serves to separate the sub key-value pair of a certain category.. for example "ca-buddhist". 
What would be the fully qualified name of a ResourceBundle with an unicode extension 'u' "ca-buddhist"?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A fully qualified resource bundle has the following form:
>   packagequalifier.bundlename + "" + language + "" + country + "" +
>   (variant + "#" | "#") + script + "-" + extensions

I don't think this definition is correct.

Have a look at the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#getBundle%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.ClassLoader%29).

Strangely, extensions (defined in [Locale](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html)) don't get mentioned...

Comment: Would you be able to provide me with an example of a fully qualified name (ResourceBundle-wise) with a unicode extension? let's say 'u' "ca-buddhist"?